# Count number of zeros in each row of large data.frame using purrr::map function

Tags: r, purrr, map-function

I have a very large dataframe 280,000 x 20 and many of the rows (obs) only have 1 or 0 values in them.  The function I'm using needs at least 2 values per operation.  I can iterate using a for loop but it takes a long time.  I would like to use one of the purrr map functions to increase speed as I will be doing this many times.  This is how I've been doing it with a for loop:

```
library(Matrix)
M1 <- as.matrix(rsparsematrix(100, 20, .1, rand.x = runif))
x <- vector("integer")
for(i in 1:dim(M1)[1]){
  l <- (length(which(M1[i,] == 0)))
  x <- c(x,l)
}
ind <- which(x == 19 | x == 20)
M1 <- M1[-ind,]
```

I haven't figured out the right way to do it in using map.  I assume it requires creating another column using mutate.

```
M1 %>% mutate(zero_count = length(map(which(. == 0))))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear about the expected.  First, we convert the `matrix` to `tibble` or `data.frame`, then `mutate` columns to logical columns, `reduce` to a single `vector` by adding (`+`) all the TRUE values in each row and `cbind` with the `vector` with the original matrix ('M1')

```
library(tidyverse)
M1 %>% 
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate_all(funs(.==0)) %>%
  reduce(`+`) %>% 
  cbind(M1, Count = .)
```

#### Update

For subsetting the rows based on the sum

```
M1 %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(.==0)) %>% 
  reduce(`+`) %>% 
  `%in%`(19:20)  %>%
  magrittr::extract(M1, .,)
```

---

With `base R`, it is `rowSums` on a logical `matrix` and `cbind` with the original `matrix`

```
cbind(M1, Count = rowSums(!M1))
```

Or subsetting with the `rowSums`

```
M1[rowSums(!M1) %in% 19:20, ]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  The new column in the data frame can filter any rows where the count equals 19 or 20 meaning the observation has only 1 or 0 values in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing with `apply`

```
apply(M1, 1 , function(x) sum(!x))
```

Comment: I was able to successfully run in a for loop but my dataset has almost 300k observations.  It took 4 min to run it using a for loop and 1 sec to run it using the purrr method @akrun provided.  I have been trying to use the tidy packages for consistency over the apply family of functions.  You are right at apply is a good option.